# Execute function across templates before compiling HTML

Tags: javascript, pug

I am building a portfolio site using pug. I am not running express, just writing my HTML with pug and using gulp to run a local server environment. Each time I make a change to a pug template, the HTML is rendered and gulp reloads my site in the browser. My site is comprised of a projects index and individual project pages. I have a function that calculates and returns the reading time of each project. Currently, this function is run from each project template page and the returned value is available on that page only.

What I'd like to do is display this reading time outside of each project on the project index. So I can show visitors the time they can expect it will take to read through each of my projects *before* they drill in.

**My question**: Can I run this function pre-compile across each project template page, store the returned values, access the returned values, and add them to my project index items?

My current thoughts are that my current project setup is too basic for this type of operation and perhaps converting to an express project would achieve my goal.

For reference, here's the code I'm running as of now:

The readTime function is stored in a main js file availble to each of my pages

```
// empty array to push function output to after its called
const dataPair = [];

/*
function that takes the project content class name as a parameter and
calculates reading time based on the amount of text content
*/
const readTime = function(contentClass) {
    const txt = document.getElementsByClassName(contentClass)[0].textContent;
    const wordCount = txt.replace( /[^\w ]/g, "" ).split( /\s+/ ).length;
    const readingTimeInMinutes = Math.floor(wordCount / 228) + 1;
    const readingTimeAsString = readingTimeInMinutes + " minute read";

  
  const readTimeOutput = {
    cls: contentClass,
    tme: readingTimeAsString
  }

  return readTimeOutput;

};
```

This function is called from the project page itself - executes readTime and pushes the project content class and reading time to the empty array

```
(() => {
  const output = readTime("project-one");
  dataPair.push(output);
})();
```

Comment: Please provide more information about the function you're running. How does it work? What does it look like?

Comment: @Sean I posted the code I'm using above. Currently, this code executes once my pug templates are compiled to HTML and the project page is loaded (clicked into). It works as expected but, the return values stored in the array are only available on the project page itself. Going back to my question, I'd like to be able to access those values outside of the project page.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to use a separate gulp task, not using pug but instead using fs, where you read each pug file and parse the number of words using regex in node, then count the words in node, then output the information as a javascript object in a JSON file, then use the include directive in your index file to read in that information, then have your pug gulp task run automatically after that first task completes.

Comment: Thank you for the direction. I figured it was going to be a more technical solution but had no idea where to start. This is super helpful!

Comment: Probably a better solution than using `include` to pull in the JSON object would be to read it into your Gulp file and then pass it as a local variable to pug